# web control access web form methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

My web form contains a web control and a asp:HiddenField. I am trying to access that hiddenfield in my asxc.cs file. I defined a public get,set block in my aspx.cs file. In web control, when I tried to call ReportPage.TestID, it does not recognize the Reportpage class. Is it the right way to access the HiddenField in the webcontrol? If so, how should I access the ReportPage class?

```
public partial class ReportPage : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public int TestID
    {
        get
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(TestIDHiddenField.Value);
        }
        set
        {
            TestIDHiddenField.Value = TestID.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You would have to show us the code you're using to call it. In other words, we need an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot directly access page controls from a user control because of [Web Site compilation model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx). In short, ASP.NET compiles first `App_code` (its classes are visible from all the site) then user controls (`.ascx`) and when `.aspx` pages which use that controls.

A workaround looks like this:

1. In `App_code` create an abstract class (`MyBasePage` for example) which inherits from `Page` class and add abstract property (`TestID` in your example),
2. Create a page which inherits from `MyBasePage` and implement the property,
3. In `.ascx.cs` cast `this.Page` as `MyBasePage` and use the property you want.

Comment: Dear downvoter, please explain. The method I explained works.